# DATABASE is mounted but 11g doesn't recognize that it's not

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I'm trying to enable archivelog on a database with

```
ALTER DATABASE ARCHIVELOG;
```

And then get

> ORA-01126: database must be mounted in this instance and not open in
>   any instance

So I ran

```
ALTER DATABASE MOUNT
```

and get

> ORA-01100: database already mounted

Answer (score 1):

After configuring archival destination shut down the database gracefully and mount it in order to enable the archive log mode.

```
SQL> shutdown immediate
SQL> Startup mount
SQL> alter database archivelog;
SQL> alter database open;
```